# Plotting a regression line through the origin

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am plotting some data series along with regression lines using this code:

```
ggplot(dt1.melt, aes(x=lower, y=value, group=variable, colour=variable)) +
    geom_point(shape=1) +    
    geom_smooth(method=lm,  
            se=FALSE)
```

However, I need to constrain the regression line to be through the origin for all series - in the same way as `abline(lm(Q75~-1+lower,data=dt1))` would achieve on a standard R plot.

Can anyone explain how to do this in `ggplot` ?

Comment: use `formula=y~x-1` in the `geom_smooth` call

Comment: @James thanks, that works beautifully - please make it an answer and I will mark it as correct.

Comment: Related to this - what if the method is no "lm", eg. "loess"? What would one force this line through the origin?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to specify this in the `formula` argument to `geom_smooth`:

```
... + geom_smooth(method=lm, se=FALSE, formula=y~x-1)
```

Comment: I was wondering how you found that formula. is it somewhere on the documentation I may have missed?