# Plotting geom_smooth/geom_spline regression line through the origin

Tags: r, ggplot2, spline, loess

Related to this question ([Plotting a regression line through the origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12651156/plotting-a-regression-line-through-the-origin)), I want to force a `geom_smooth(method="loess")` call through the origin (0). For `geom_smooth(method="lm")`, this is possible by specifying the formula in the call, ie `geom_smooth(method=lm, formula=y~x-1)`. What would be the equivalent for `geom_smooth(method="loess")`?

Answer (score 1):

This is an odd thing to want to do. A `loess` regression is a *locally adaptive* fit, so you cannot constrain it to pass through the origin unless you include in your regression a heavily weighted point (or tight cluster of points) at the origin. This is a bit artificial at best.

If you were able to expand on what you are trying to achieve and what your data represents, there may be a better option, but in the meantime, you could achieve what you are asking like this.

First, let's set up a simple example:

```r
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1)

df <- data.frame(x = 0:10, y = rnorm(11, 0:10) + 5)

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + 
       geom_point() + 
       coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, 10), ylim = c(0, 20)) +
       theme_bw(base_size = )
```

Our standard `geom_smooth` call would look like this:

```r
p + geom_smooth(formula = y ~ x, method = "loess")
```

[image]

And to force it through the origin we can do:

```r
p + geom_smooth(data = rbind(df, data.frame(x = 0, y = 0)),
                formula = y ~ x,
                aes(weight = c(rep(1, nrow(df)), 100)),
                method = "loess")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-12-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>